# Comma-separated values analysis and pivot tables in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, csv

I have an issue with comma-separated values analysis and pivot tables in Google Spreadsheets. What if I have the following dataset:

```
Facebook, Github      Developer
No answer             Developer
Github, MSDN          Developer
Facebook, Github      Developer
Artstation            Designer
Beahnca, Artstation   Designer
3DTotal               Designer
```

As a result I want to see the following grouping:

```
           Facebook Github  No answer   MSDN    3DTotal Artstation  Behance
Developer   2        3          1        1       0          0       0
Designer    0        0          0        0       1          2       1
```

How can I do that? Please assist.
The main problem is how to transform

```
Facebook, Github      Developer
No answer             Developer
Github, MSDN          Developer
```

to

```
Facebook              Developer
No answer             Developer
Github                Developer
Github                Developer
Github                Developer
MSDN                  Developer
```

and after that I can create a pivot table without any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this once, rather than dealing with automatic processing of CSV files:

1. Reorder the columns by dragging, so that the comma-separated one is on the right (say, it's now column B)
2. Select the comma-separated column and choose "Data > Split text to columns" from the menu. That column will be split into several (two in your example: B and C)
3. Use the formula `={filter({B1:B, A1:A}, len(B1:B)); filter({C1:C, A1:A}, len(C1:C))}` (possibly with more columns, if you have more of them after splitting). It produces a site-category array based on each of the columns obtained in step 2, and joins them. The filtering removes blank cells that are going to appear when some comma-separated strings have fewer elements than others.

The output is the two-column table of the form that you seek.

Comment: It works! Great! The splitting returnes me B:G columns. In that case my formula will look like `={filter({B2:B, A2:A}, len(B2:B)); filter({C2:C, A2:A}, len(C2:C)); filter({D2:D, A2:A}, len(D2:D)); filter({E2:E, A2:A}, len(E2:E)); filter({F2:F, A2:A}, len(F2:F)); filter({G2:G, A2:A}, len(G2:G))}` Am I right? Is here any way to do it more readable? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks  right and no, I don't think there is a shorter way to express that, considering one can't put a for loop into a spreadsheet formula.